# C++ Cross Correlation of 2 shifted images with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to do a cross correlation of 2 shifted images. In general I would do it like this:
- Load the 2 images
- make an dft with this 2 images
- multiply this images with each other with mulSpectrum (opencv)
- make an inverse dft of the result of the multipliation
- show the result--in the result image there must be a shift of the frequency, which is the shift of the real images.
I have done this with openCV:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void fft_shift(Mat &I, Mat &magI) //shift the origin to the center of the image (taken from OpenCV example of dft)
{
    Mat padded;                            //expand input image to optimal size
    int m = getOptimalDFTSize(I.rows);
    int n = getOptimalDFTSize(I.cols); // on the border add zero values
    copyMakeBorder(I, padded, 0, m - I.rows, 0, n - I.cols, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0));

    Mat planes[] = { Mat_<float>(padded), Mat::zeros(padded.size(), CV_32F) };
    Mat complexI;
    merge(planes, 2, complexI);         // Add to the expanded another plane with zeros

    dft(complexI, complexI);            // this way the result may fit in the source matrix

                                        // compute the magnitude and switch to logarithmic scale
                                        // => log(1 + sqrt(Re(DFT(I))^2 + Im(DFT(I))^2))
    split(complexI, planes);                   // planes[0] = Re(DFT(I), planes[1] = Im(DFT(I))
    magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);// planes[0] = magnitude
    magI = planes[0];

    magI += Scalar::all(1);                    // switch to logarithmic scale
    log(magI, magI);

    // crop the spectrum, if it has an odd number of rows or columns
    magI = magI(Rect(0, 0, magI.cols & -2, magI.rows & -2));

    // rearrange the quadrants of Fourier image  so that the origin is at the image center
    int cx = magI.cols / 2;
    int cy = magI.rows / 2;

    Mat q0(magI, Rect(0, 0, cx, cy));   // Top-Left - Create a ROI per quadrant
    Mat q1(magI, Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy));  // Top-Right
    Mat q2(magI, Rect(0, cy, cx, cy));  // Bottom-Left
    Mat q3(magI, Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy)); // Bottom-Right

    Mat tmp;                           // swap quadrants (Top-Left with Bottom-Right)
    q0.copyTo(tmp);
    q3.copyTo(q0);
    tmp.copyTo(q3);

    q1.copyTo(tmp);                    // swap quadrant (Top-Right with Bottom-Left)
    q2.copyTo(q1);
    tmp.copyTo(q2);


}

int main()
{

//load images and convert them to greyscale
    Mat I = imread("original_Image.png");
    cv::cvtColor(I, I, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat II = imread("shifted_Image.png");
    cv::cvtColor(II, II, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    if (I.empty())
        return -1;

    // call the fft_shift function and multiply this to spectrum
    Mat mag1, mag1_shift, mag3,mag4;
    fft_shift(I,mag1);
    fft_shift(II, mag1_shift);
    mulSpectrums(mag1, mag1_shift,mag3, 0, 1);

    //perform an inverse dft and shift it, then normalize is for displaying
    cv::dft(mag3, mag3, cv::DFT_INVERSE | cv::DFT_REAL_OUTPUT);
    fft_shift(mag3, mag4);    
    normalize(mag4, mag4, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX);    
    imshow("spectrum shift", mag4);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result of this calculations: result

[image]

And here is the result I expected: expected result

[image]

this result was taken out of a python programm from: http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.11.x/auto_examples/plot_register_translation.html I try to translate this code to C++, which is the code above, but it is not working. Does anybody know, what I´m doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or I can use just:

Point2d phaseCorrelate(InputArray src1, InputArray src2, InputArray window=noArray())

that´s doing all the stuff for me

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution from the second post of this page:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/1624/phase-correlation-for-image-registrationimage-stitching/
The result of this code is:

[image: Result of the taken code from the link above]

Now I have to normalize this image, to see only the shiftet point.

So before you make an ifft, you have to normalize the result of the mulspectrum (code snipped taken out from the link above):

```
mulSpectrums(fft1,fft2,fft1,0,true);
fft1 = fft1/abs(fft1) //-->new
idft(fft1,fft1);
```

After this, you have to swap the quadrants, like in the openCV example:

```
// crop the spectrum, if it has an odd number of rows or columns
    fft1 = fft1(Rect(0, 0, fft1.cols & -2, fft1.rows & -2));
    // rearrange the quadrants of Fourier image  so that the origin is at the image center
    int cx = fft1.cols / 2;
    int cy = fft1.rows / 2;

    Mat q0(fft1, Rect(0, 0, cx, cy));   // Top-Left - Create a ROI per quadrant
    Mat q1(fft1, Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy));  // Top-Right
    Mat q2(fft1, Rect(0, cy, cx, cy));  // Bottom-Left
    Mat q3(fft1, Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy)); // Bottom-Right

    Mat tmp;                           // swap quadrants (Top-Left with Bottom-Right)
    q0.copyTo(tmp);
    q3.copyTo(q0);
    tmp.copyTo(q3);

    q1.copyTo(tmp);                    // swap quadrant (Top-Right with Bottom-Left)
    q2.copyTo(q1);
    tmp.copyTo(q2);
```

Now the result looks like the one from the python code:

[image: final result]

Answer (score 0):

You may make error on the inverse fft's scale, since you `mulSpectrums`, you need to divide (width*height)^2 for correct result, other than normalize it.

You may take my recipe:

```cpp
cv::Mat XCorrelation(cv::Mat const& I, cv::Mat const& I1) 
    {
        int width = cv::getOptimalDFTSize(std::max(I.cols,I1.cols));
        int height = cv::getOptimalDFTSize(std::max(I.rows,I1.rows));
        cv::Mat fft1;
        cv::Mat fft2;

        cv::copyMakeBorder(I, fft1, 0, height - I.rows, 0, width - I.cols, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(0));
        cv::copyMakeBorder(I1, fft2, 0, height - I.rows, 0, width - I.cols, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(0));

        fft1.convertTo(fft1, CV_32F);
        fft2.convertTo(fft2, CV_32F);

        cv::dft(fft1,fft1,0,I.rows);
        cv::dft(fft2,fft2,0,I1.rows);

        cv::mulSpectrums(fft1,fft2,fft1,0,true);
        // here cv::DFT_SCALE divide `width*height` 1 times
        cv::idft(fft1,fft1,cv::DFT_SCALE|cv::DFT_REAL_OUTPUT);
        Rearrange(fft1, fft1);
        // here divide another times
        return cv::abs(fft1)/(width*height);
    }
```

The `Rearrange` function is the same with your `fft_shift` as follows:

```cpp
void Rearrange(cv::Mat& src, cv::Mat& dst)
    {
        int cx = src.cols / 2;
        int cy = src.rows / 2;
        cv::Mat tmp;
        tmp.create(src.size(), src.type());
        src(cv::Rect(0, 0, cx, cy)).copyTo(tmp(cv::Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy)));
        src(cv::Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy)).copyTo(tmp(cv::Rect(0, 0, cx, cy)));
        src(cv::Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy)).copyTo(tmp(cv::Rect(0, cy, cx, cy)));
        src(cv::Rect(0, cy, cx, cy)).copyTo(tmp(cv::Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy)));
        dst = tmp;
    }
```

And for famous Lena with a shift (dx=30, dy=20), i got a result image looks similar with your python output:

[Lena3020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obBhP.png)